# using the first and last character of a string to create another variable

Tags: r, string, dplyr

My data looks like this:

```
df <- tibble(code = c("B12345A", "B12345C"))
```

I want to create a second variable, say 'code_2', that takes the first and last character of the string in the first variable like this:

```
df <- df %>% 
mutate(code_2 = str_sub(code, 1, 1), 
       code_3 = str_sub(code, 7, 7)) %>% 
unite(code_2, 2:3, sep = "", remove = TRUE)
```

But surely there's a more succinct way to achieve the above using dplyr tools? (I'm thinking I could create a function to achieve this too, but I'm not sure how to go about that either.) Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mutate(code_2 = paste0(substr(code,1,1), substr(code,7,7)))`
```

Or if the length of the strings can vary:

```
mutate(code_2 = paste0(substr(code,1,1), substr(code,nchar(code),nchar(code))))
```

Change `substr` to `str_sub` if you prefer the function from the `stringr` package.

You could also use a regular expression:

```
mutate(code_2 = gsub("(.).*(.)", "\\1\\2", code))
```